# Remove the deleted values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I have two arrays such as,

**Array 1**:

```
    deletedValuesfromArray =
     [
        { "property_name": "Property three", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 2 }, 
        { "property_name": "rstywrtre", "property_type": 3, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
     ]
```

**Array 2:**

```
  normalArray =
   [
    { "property_name": "Property one", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 },
     { "property_name": "Property two", "property_type": 5, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }, 
     { "property_name": "Property three", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 2 }, 
     { "property_name": "rstywrtre", "property_type": 3, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
   ]
```

I would like to compare both arrays and filter the array to get the new one after removing the `deletedValuesfromArray` (Array 1).

For which i have tried the following,

```
let newArray = this.normalArray.filter(function (val) {
  return this.deletedValuesfromArray.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

But it doesn't works..

Expected Output is,

**New Array**

```
   [
     { "property_name": "Property one", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 },
     { "property_name": "Property two", "property_type": 5, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
   ]
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snctb9) that i have tried

The values also will not be unique always it may have a complete duplicate of any object.

How to compare and remove the deleted values from the normal array and get the newarray?

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` predicate doesn't work because you can't just compare an object from `normalArray` to an object from `deletedValuesfromArray`:

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the `Array` using
>   strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals
>   operator).

-- [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description)

In other words,

```
{ "property_name": "Property one", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 } === { "property_name": "Property one", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
// > false
```

To make the `filter` work, you need to implement a comparison function. See [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with **ES6 operators** (*filter* and *some*) :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let newArray = this.normalArray.filter( (val) => {
      return !this.deletedValuesfromArray.some((newval) => {
       return JSON.stringify(newval) === JSON.stringify(val) // check if two objects are the same
      });
    });
    console.log(newArray);
  }
```

Comment: Here you're assuming that `property_name` values are unique. The OP never said that

Comment: Yes this solution seems to be close to me but the thing is as @shkaper said the values may not be unique at all time..

Comment: this is potentially dangerous since object's property order is not guaranteed in JavaScript

Comment: If you need an explanation about why this solution is terrible, please consider how much cpu time is wasted to stringify all those objects. You are also stringifying the same object way too many times with the way this loop works. You are also not taking into account that there is no spec in javascript that says that the order of object properties stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

one of simple options here you can use `JSON.stringify`, which will turn objects into strings and compare them as strings, because 2 objects never equal each other by value since it compares them by reference, make sure that your objects keys order are the same

```js
const deletedValuesfromArray =
     [
        { "property_name": "Property three", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 2 }, 
        { "property_name": "rstywrtre", "property_type": 3, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
     ]

  const normalArray =
   [
    { "property_name": "Property one", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 },
     { "property_name": "Property two", "property_type": 5, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }, 
     { "property_name": "Property three", "property_type": 4, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 2 }, 
     { "property_name": "rstywrtre", "property_type": 3, "property_required": true, "property_origin": 1 }
   ]

const result = normalArray.filter(obj => !deletedValuesfromArray.find(o => JSON.stringify(o) == JSON.stringify(obj)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if the order of keys is different in two same-looking objects?

Comment: @shkaper the order is important in my example, I will update my answer

Comment: I can explain the down vote. Using stringify is a terrible solution and the guy that made the question didn't say that he wants to check that the two objects are exactly identical. You should *NEVER* expect that the order of keys is the same.

Comment: @itsundefined from the question it is easy to get that he wants to check that the two objects are exactly identical. Almost all answers contain the same logic, as accepted answer too which marked by question creator, it means we got question right, and I noted that in my example order is important,  so I don't see any reason for down vote, it seems you got question wrong and added down votes to answers which have upvote

Comment: @itsundefined I'm not using this method for removing objects from array, I'm using this method for comparing objects, 2 different things

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order . Here is the reason for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash :-

```
npm install --save lodash


import * as _ from "lodash";

var newArray = _.differenceWith(this.normalArray, this.deletedValuesfromArray, _.isEqual);
console.log("newArray", newArray);
```

Comment: FYI, lodash is swiss army knife of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This might also help you.

```
function display()
{
  let newArray = this.normalArray.filter(function (val) {
  count = 0;
  var flag = true;
  return this.deletedValuesfromArray.find(function(item, i){
  count++;

     if(val.property_name == item.property_name && val.property_type == item.property_type && val.property_required == item.property_required && val.property_origin == item.property_origin ){
       flag =  false;
     }
     if(count == deletedValuesfromArray.length) {
     return flag;
     }
  });
```

});
   }